# ActionLink inside an if statement inside a webgrid

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a webgrid that I am making, and I want one of the columns to display a download link to a file on the server if there is one, and the words "no file uploaded" if there is not. I tried to do something like this, but then I get an error that says:

Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

```
 grid.Column( header: "File", format: @<span>
           @if (item.personfile != null) { 
         (item) => (@Html.ActionLink("Download file", "downloadFile", "Person", new { id = item.id }, null))
           }
```

I need to use the actionlink but I don't know how to incorporate it with the rest of the html. I haven't bothered making an else condition yet because this piece of code doesn't seem to work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code. Here is the working sample - https://dotnetfiddle.net/tjl1Ka

```
grid.Column( header: "File",
     format:(item) => (item.personfile != null)
     ? Html.ActionLink("Download file", "downloadFile", "Person", new { id = item.id })
     : Html.Raw("No File Found"))
```

Comment: Weird, I got the following error: Compiler Error Message: CS0136: A local variable named 'item' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'item', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else@ramiramilu

Comment: Are you using `item` anywhere else? And by the way, I forgot ')' in the first solution, i update the solution. Also changed the format to make it little more easy, try this now.

Comment: hmm, yes I was. I guess I'm kinda confused as..it seems that item serves as a way to access the model but since I'm using a lambda expression, I should use another variable other than item? (I'm completely new at lambda expressions) @ramiramilu

Comment: Let me know if my solution doesn't works, I will try to give you a different version.

Comment: I changed the variable from "item" to "x" and now am getting a new error: : The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.HelperResult(System.Action<System.IO.TextWriter>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: I replicated the same code I posted as answer, and I was able to make it work - https://dotnetfiddle.net/tjl1Ka. So please check your other parts of the code.